# NIntegrate on a solution of a matrix ODE

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, numerical-value

I've seen similar questions on this site but somehow the solutions there didn't manage to solve my specific problem.

I have a function *mat1* that takes a square $n \times n$ matrix *G*, and some final time *tfinal*, and solves the following ODE numerically:
$$u'(t) = G(t) u(t)$$
$$u(0) = \mathrm{id}_{n\times n}$$
The code is:

```
mat1[G_, tfinal_] := Block[{t}, NDSolveValue[{u'[t] == G[t].u[t], u[0] == IdentityMatrix[Dimensions[G[0]][[1]]]}, u, {t, 0, tfinal},
Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"]]
```

Let's take an example matrix-valued function $g(t)$:

```
g[t_?NumericQ] := {{Sin[t], 0}, {Cos[t], t}}
```

Mathematica has no problems solving the ODE with g as the input matrix:

```
mat1[g, 10][1.21]
(*Result: {{1.90977, 0.}, {1.92296, 2.07912}}*)
```

But when I want to numerically integrate it, I get the following error:

```
NIntegrate[mat1[g, 10][t], {t, 0, 10}]
(*NIntegrate::inum: Integrand InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.}},{5,3,1,{98},{4},0,0,0,0,Automatic,{},{},False},{{0.,0.120666,0.60333,0.874901,<<43>>,6.97746,7.05172,7.12517,<<48>>}},{{{{1.,0.},{0.,1.}},{{0.,0.},{1.,0.}}},{{{1.0073,0.},{0.121253,1.00731}},{{0.121252,0.},{1.0146,0.121548}}},<<48>>,<<48>>},{Automatic}][t] is not numerical at {t} = {0.000960178}.*)
(*NIntegrate::inum: Integrand InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.}},{5,3,1,{98},{4},0,0,0,0,Automatic,{},{},False},{{0.,0.120666,0.60333,0.874901,<<43>>,6.97746,7.05172,7.12517,<<48>>}},{{{{1.,0.},{0.,1.}},{{0.,0.},{1.,0.}}},{{{1.0073,0.},{0.121253,1.00731}},{{0.121252,0.},{1.0146,0.121548}}},<<48>>,<<48>>},{Automatic}][t] is not numerical at {t} = {0.000960178}.*)
```

I've also tried defining a function in between:

```
mat2[t_?NumericQ] := mat1[g, 10][t]
```

But I get the same error:

```
NIntegrate[mat2[t], {t, 0, 10}]
(*NIntegrate::inum: Integrand mat2[t] is not numerical at {t} = {0.0795732}.*)
```

It looks like even with the NumericQ, Mathematica is trying to manipulate the integrand with a symbolic $t$ before putting numbers in.

**EDIT:**

It looks like the above code works fine for a real-valued function, as opposed to matrices:

```
mat1[G_, tfinal_] := Block[{t}, NDSolveValue[{u'[t] == G[t]*u[t], u[0] ==1},u, {t, 0, tfinal}, Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"]]

g[t_?NumericQ] := Sin[t]

NIntegrate[mat1[g, 10][t], {t, 0, 10}]

(*Result: 36.4662*)
```

So it looks like the problem has something to do with $g$ being a matrix. I'm not sure how though.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, Sahand! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign!

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126041/34008) is an answer to a related question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message says, the problem is that `mat2[0.0795732]` is not numerical. It is instead a 2x2 matrix of numbers. You could do something like:

```
mat2[t_?NumericQ] := mat1[g, 10][t][[1,1]]
NIntegrate[mat2[t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

> 36.4662

On the other hand, it is much simpler to just have [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) do the integration for you:

```
mat1[G_,tfinal_] := NDSolveValue[
    {
    int'[t] == u[t], int[0] == ConstantArray[0, Dimensions[G[0]]],
    u'[t]==G[t].u[t], u[0]==IdentityMatrix[Dimensions[G[0]][[1]]]
    },
    {u, int},
    {t,0,tfinal}
]
```

Then:

```
mat1[g, 10]
```

> [image]

and:

```
mat1[g, 10][[2]][10]
```

> {{36.4662, 0.}, {3.69638*10^20, 5.23821*10^20}}

agreeing with the above result.

Comment: I see! So Mathematica also counts matrices with numerical elements as "non-numerical". So I have to integrate it element-wise, or use NDSolve. So is there no direct way to integrate matrices with NIntegrate itself?

Comment: @SahandTabatabaei Yes, there is a direct way to integrate matrices with `NIntegrate`. I will post a related answer after a day or two. (I plan to extend the rule described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126041/34008) or program new one...)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Integrate` to directly antidifferentiate an interpolating function.  If $f(t)$ is an interpolating function with domain $(a,b)$, `Integrate[f[t], t]` returns an interpolating function with the same domain equal to
$$\int_a^t f(\tau) \; d\tau\,.$$

To get the definite integral, plug the end point:

```
Integrate[mat1[g, 10][t], t] /. t -> 10
(*  {{36.4662, 0.}, {3.69611*10^20, 5.23781*10^20}}  *)
```

Comment: You could also use `Derivative[-1][mat1[g, 10]]` to construct the interpolating function without an argument, e.g., `Derivative[-1][mat1[g, 10]][10]` so that no ReplaceAll is needed.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks. I was going to add that if the OP wanted greater accuracy, using `InterpolationOrder -> All`in `NDSolve` would likely produce a more accurate integral (by either of our methods, I suppose), but that option does not work with matrix ODEs and certain methods, such `"ExplicitRungeKutta"` with a difference order greater than 3.  (Just reported as [CASE:4249898].)