# Extract symbolically processed form of NIntegrated function

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning

As I understand NIntegrate does some symbolic preprocessing of inputs before it actually goes ahead and numerically integrates. I'm wondering if there is some way to access this intermediate preconditioned form.

Let me demonstrate:

```
expr[a_, b_, c_] = -((a xp + b yp - c zp)/Sqrt[(0.5` - xp)^2 + yp^2 + zp^2]);
dom = Triangle[{{0.`, 0.`, 1.`}, {0.25, 0.8, 0.4}, {-0.7, 0.5, 0.4}}];
Timing[NIntegrate[expr[1,2,3], {xp, yp, zp} \[Element] dom]]
Timing[NIntegrate[expr[1,2,3], {xp, yp, zp} \[Element] dom, 
  Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]]

{0.03125, 0.474964}
{0.21875, 0.47448}
```

As you can see there's a healthy performance gain when allowing NIntegrate to precondition its inputs.

I need to compute thousands+ of similar integrals over different domains and different parameters. It would be nice if I could get access to this preconditioned form so I could inject my parameters directly into that or perhaps compile it, rather than duplicating this simplification step each time.

Comment: Maybe, you should ask about how to speed up the computation of thousands of similar integrals, not (just) how to get the symbolic pre-processing forms of `NIntegrate`.

Comment: @AntonAntonov That sounds like a great idea. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234887/speed-up-the-computation-of-many-similar-numerical-integrals-over-2d-regions-emb

Comment: @AntonAntonov is there a way to adapt your answer here to solving problems of this kind (multi-dimensional)? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126001/how-to-calculate-the-numerical-integral-more-efficiently/126041#126041
I noticed that in ArrayOfFunctionsRule.m, multidimensional integration is listed as a todo.

Comment: Yes, I as thinking to adapt that answer to your problem last week(end), but did not have time to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`IntegrationMonitor`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96663) to examine the integrals and regions `NIntegrate` computes with after the symbolic preprocessing.

Here is an example:

```
NIntegrate[expr[1, 2, 3], {xp, yp, zp} \[Element] dom, 
 MaxRecursion -> 0, PrecisionGoal -> 1, IntegrationMonitor -> Print]

(* During evaluation of In[35]:= {NIntegrate`IntegrationRegion[{{0,0},{1,1}},Experimental`NumericalFunction[{xp,yp},-((3.21926 (1-xp) (-0.821918+1. xp+0.575342 (1-xp) yp))/Sqrt[1.17647 -1.36471 xp+1. xp^2-0.470588 (1-xp) yp+1.10118 (1-xp) xp yp+1.03529 (1-xp)^2 yp^2]),-NumericalFunctionData-],{},NIntegrate`MultiDimensionalRule[{{{{0.,0.},{0.179284,0.},{0.474342,0.},{0.474342,0.474342},{0.344124,0.344124}},{-0.193873,0.149367,0.0518214,0.0101611,0.0871183},{1.13809,-0.354748,0.00723975,-0.0241325,0.0871183}},{{},{},{},{}},{2,5,-1}}]]} *)

(* 0.474984 *)
```

[image]